# When building a REST API, must I use status codes?

Tags: rest, api-design, http-status-codes

I'm developing a web application that has a backend API, which is going to be primarily used by a reference frontend application, but other clients can use it too.

The data my API sends has a specific type structure. I'm using Rust's type system, which has enums whose options may have additional data inside them. For example, the responses of a route that retrieves an article may be modeled like:

```rust
#[derive(serde::Serialize)]
#[serde(tag = "status")]
enum ArticleGetResult {
  Exists {
    name: String,
    content: String,
    score: i32,
  },
  NotFound,
  Redirected {
    new_id: usize,
  },
  DatabaseError {
    error_text: String,
  }
}
```

It's considered good form to provide useful status codes in APIs, and also headers, and the backend does send those when applicable. However, because of technical reasons, it's somewhat difficult to get access to these in the frontend code, so instead I only use the response body and ignore the status code and headers.

```
-> GET /articles/1
<- 200 OK
{"status": "Exists", "name": "Article", "content": "article content", "score": 5}

-> GET /articles/2
<- 404 Not Found
{"status": "NotFound"}

-> GET /articles/3
<- 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /articles/4
{"status": "Redirected", "new_id": 4}

-> GET /articles/4
<- 500 Internal Server Error
{"status": "DatabaseError", "error_text": "some error happened"}
```

Are there any particular downsides to not using the status code and header info in client code, and instead only using the response body's info?

Comment: _"It's considered good form to provide useful status codes in APIs"_ - by whom exactly?

Comment: @GuruStron I don't have a real source for this, but I do observe that most APIs I've encountered make use of status codes. Also, there's the opinion ([expressed through memes](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/jnb9fa)) that returning a 200 OK envelope containing an error body is bad.

Comment: 1) Don't remember seeing such APIs at all TBH 2) I would argue that the "providing useful status codes in APIs"  is what exactly can lead to the behavior which is made fun of in the linked meme.

Comment: @GuruStron usefulness of status codes in REST APIs is supported by Microsoft best practices: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design#conform-to-http-semantics, they advice to follow HTTP semantics, within which there is a section with status codes https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15. Microsoft even shows examples of how to use the status codes.

Comment: @banan3'14 yes, it seems that I misunderstood OP (as it becomes clear when checking the second point of my comment), I was talking about adding status info to the body, not the status code itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any particular downsides to not using the status code and header info in client code, and instead only using the response body's info?

Yes - largely it comes down to this: you may be limiting the kinds of HTTP intermediates you can introduce into your system.  In other words, can your system still work if the client is passing its traffic to a proxy, or the server is receiving its traffic from a reverse proxy?

The problem being that these components will be assuming that other components sending and receiving HTTP messages will understand HTTP, and will expect those components to be able to correctly handle HTTP metadata.

Example: some network error occurs, and the system starts sending general purpose 504 Gateway Timeout responses with some message body that you don't control.  How does your client interpret that message?

Part of the point of choosing a general purpose application protocol (HTTP) is so that we can use general purpose components to do a lot of the heavy lifting, rather than building everything for ourselves.

---

In a situation where you control the client, the server, and the topology in between, those concerns might be less important to you than (for example) the advantages of writing the client in the style that you suggest.

And that's fine.

I'd suggest capturing in a decision record all of the factors that you considered when making this choice, so that they can be reviewed by posterity if local conditions change.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any particular downsides to not using the status code and header info in client code, and instead only using the response body's info?

I would argue that the main one would be the violation of the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle - i.e. you would have two sources of the same knowledge (i.e. actual status of the response) with all corresponding consequences, like potential desync which can lead to something like the linked in the comments meme:

[image]

> However, because of technical reasons, it's somewhat difficult to get access to these in the frontend code

Sounds like a problem which should be fixed on frontend side, adding the status code information sounds more like a (temporary) hack then actual solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if putting status field in the body violates DRY rule, provided that it's well documented and consistent across all the endpoints, and the client relies only on the status field and not on the HTTP code. It doesn't duplicate the knowledge as the HTTP status code is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Status codes are an integral part of the HTTP protocol, and they play a crucial role in REST APIs. They provide standardized ways for a server to communicate the outcome of a client's request. Status codes and headers weren't there in the first version of the protocol – HTTP 1.0, but they were added to provide a standard and good practice. Following a convention in your project makes it less confusing for other developers and easier to develop the client. With your `status` in the body, you're reinventing a wheel and it's already not RESTful API at all. It's harder to version such API and follow the specific contract, you have to make the client code more complicated to provide a specific enum for all status cases instead of using a way provided in all modern frameworks. Also, are you sure you can implement statelessness and cacheability in the right way? You might even lose the opportunity of caching and optimization the browsers provide, not even mentioning the safeness of your solution. Can you do the error handling in the correct way? There are a lot of such questions that makes the standard much better way than reinventing the wheel with your own `status`.