# search for how to remove meta data in my api response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a meta data in my API response and I want to delete.

This is the response:

```json
{
  "$id": "1",
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": {
    "$id": "2",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$id": "3",
        "id": 3,
        "comment": "hello",
        "createdAt": "2024/1/29",
        "student": "Student Mahmoud",
        "lessonId": 1011
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm using the status code:

```
return StatusCode(
        200,
        new
        {
            statusCode = 200,
            studentCourses
        }
    );
```

where `studentCourses` is coming from the database.

The response I want is:

```json
{

  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "comment": "hello",
        "createdAt": "2024/1/29",
        "student": "Student Mahmoud",
        "lessonId": 1011
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to have somehing more of code instead of result.
Also look take a look at existing issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542144/how-to-remove-id-during-json-serialization/12748861

Comment: Was not able to repro. Can you please post some a [mre]?

Comment: Also I highly recommend against returning status in the response body - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76869606/2501279